# npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree jspdf

Tags: angular

I have the following dependency problems, it already deletes the modules folder I have thrown a --force but nothing works. I share my dependencies in case you can see which one is compatible and does not cause conflicts

It is a project that I clone directly and do an npm install.
retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps

```
{
  "name": "arquetipo-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.2.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.4.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^13.0.4",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "angular-datatables": "^8.0.0",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.21",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.21",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.9",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "materialize-css": "^0.100.2",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-materialize": "^6.1.3",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.13.0",
    "unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript": "^1.0.4",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.18",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "get-google-fonts": "^1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's saying you are using `jspdf` version `1.5.3` in your project. You are also using `jspdf-autotable` which requires `jspdf` version `2.5.1` as a peer dependency (which means your project).

So, what you need to do is use `"jspdf": "^2.5.1",` - this is the latest version anyway, take a look at [the jspdf version history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf?activeTab=versions) - you are currently using a version from 5 years ago!

Comment: If I update to 2.5.1 but when doing that update it generates another conflict with another dependency

npm ERR! While resolving: angular-archetype@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR! @angular/animations@"~8.2.9" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/animations@"^6.0.0-rc.0 || ^6.0.0" from ngx-materialize@6.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/ngx-materialize
npm ERR! ngx-materialize@"^6.1.3" from the root project

Comment: I would advise you to just update everything in your package file to the latest version, then delete your `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` files, then run `npm install`.

Comment: If I do that, but I have the same message

Comment: Try just updating `jspdf` and then **delete** `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install`.  Most of your packages related to Angular and Typescript are 4-5 years old.  You either need to lock the versions down so they don't auto-update or you need to modernize you application with the latest versions.

Comment: I had to downgrade node to 14 and install npm and ngx-print@1.2.1 thanks